# Magento bulk import customer and send email confirmation

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, email-templates

We want to create account for customers in bulk. How can i import customers and send confirmation email in magento?

Answer (score 0):

Loop over your data and use the built in [Magento customer methods](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/customer#customer.create).

Comment: @chris Thanks for quick reply. Could you please suggest any extension or any custom code that helps in sending bulk email to customer during import?

Comment: You're looping over each customer to create... what's wrong with using [PHP's mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)?